# Filtering vector of maps based on a blacklist

Tags: clojure

Given a vector of maps:

```
(def my-list
  [{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
    {:a 1 :b 5 :c 6}
    {:a 7 :b 8 :c 12}
    {:a 10 :b 11 :c 12}])
```

and a blacklist:

```
(def blacklist
  [{:a 1 :c 3}
    {:a 10 :c 12}])
```

the expected output is:

```
[{:a 1 :b 5 :c 6}
  {:a 7 :b 8 :c 12}]
```

I came up with:

```
(defn not-excluded?
  [blacklist item]
  (not-any? (fn [exclusion-item]
              (and (= (:a item) (:a exclusion-item))
                   (= (:c item) (:c exclusion-item))))
            blacklist))

(filter (partial not-excluded? blacklist) my-list)
```

but there is probably a more idiomatic Clojure way.

Comment: I don't Clojure very well, but requiring `:a` and `:c` to be hardcoded in the function doesn't look like a good solution. Have you considered passing those as arguments instead?

Comment: Yeah, that's one thing, that can be improved for sure. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to exclude from the vector (more generally a sequence) the maps of which any map in the blacklist is a sub-map. Let's define a function that tests whether its first argument is a sub-map of its second argument:

```
(defn submap? [a b]
  (every? (fn [[k v]] (= v (b k)))  a))
```

For instance,

```
=> (map #(submap? {1 2} %) [{} {1 1} {1 2}])
(false false true)
```

So far, so good. Let's use `submap?` to define function `clean` that takes a blacklist and a sequence of maps as arguments, excluding any supermaps of any map in the blacklist from the sequence:

```
(defn clean [blacklist ms]
  (filter
    (fn [m] (not-any? #(submap? % m) blacklist))
    ms))
```

For example,

```
=> (clean blacklist my-list)
({:a 1, :b 5, :c 6} {:a 7, :b 8, :c 12})
```

---

`submap?` could be careful about absent keys. If you have `nil` values, you need to fix this.